# Snowflake: [42000][904] SQL compilation error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When trying to execute this request I got an issue:

```
[42000][904] SQL compilation error: error line 5 at position 24 invalid identifier 'SRC.AGE'


merge into Test_functionality as target
using (select *
        from (values ('36', 1, 25, 2.9, '00000101'), ('37', 1, 25, 2.9, '00000101'), ('38', 1, 25, 2.9, '00000101'), ('39', 1, 25, 2.9, '00000101')))
        as src(age, SomeBoolean, SomeNumber, SomeDouble, SomeBinary)
    on target.age = src.age
when matched then update set target.age = src.age, target.SomeBoolean = src.SomeBoolean, target.SomeNumber = src.SomeNumber, target.SomeDouble = src.SomeDouble, target.SomeBinary = src.SomeBinary
when not matched then insert (age, SomeBoolean, SomeNumber, SomeDouble, SomeBinary) values (src.age, src.SomeBoolean, src.SomeNumber, src.SomeDouble, src.SomeBinary);
```

The table what I use:

```
CREATE TABLE Test_functionality (
    age                        VARCHAR,
    SomeBoolean                BOOLEAN,
    SomeNumber                 INT,
    SomeDouble                 real,
    SomeBinary                 binary
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
merge into Test_functionality as target
using (select column1 age, column2 SomeBoolean, column3 SomeNumber, column4 SomeDouble, column5 SomeBinary
        from (values ('36', 1, 25, 2.9, '00000101'), ('37', 1, 25, 2.9, '00000101'), ('38', 1, 25, 2.9, '00000101'), ('39', 1, 25, 2.9, '00000101')))
        as src
    on target.age = src.age
when matched then update set target.age = src.age, target.SomeBoolean = src.SomeBoolean, target.SomeNumber = src.SomeNumber, target.SomeDouble = src.SomeDouble, target.SomeBinary = src.SomeBinary
when not matched then insert (age, SomeBoolean, SomeNumber, SomeDouble, SomeBinary) values (src.age, src.SomeBoolean, src.SomeNumber, src.SomeDouble, src.SomeBinary);
```